# can't drag element that has css property unset: all

Tags: css, draggable, unset

It seems I'm not able to drag an element that has `unset: all` css property.

```
.my-component {
  all: initial;
  * {
    all: unset;
  }
}
```

I use these rules inside a chrome extension, on elements that are being injected in the user browser page (to prevent local style affecting my component). Unfortunately, elements are not draggable anymore.

Those elements have the `draggable` property on in html.

I tried `pointer-events: auto;`, `-webkit-user-drag: auto;`, `user-select: all;` but I still can't manage to make elements draggable.

There must be some properties I have to set back to normal.

If someone had an idea, I would highly appreciate any help on this topic.

Edit : see this codepen - https://codepen.io/thomaslh/pen/OgQNMz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need to add 2 CSS properties. `user-select` and `-webkit-user-drag`

```css
.el {
  all: unset;
  -webkit-user-drag: element;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="el" draggable="true">
  drag
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that's doing the job ;) Blazing fast answer.

Comment: @ThomasL'huillier sweet, you're welcome! Good question, I think this might come up more as people use draggable/all more.